# '$validate' is declared but not used.intelephense

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my program to create login and register pages

In the validate section I did not find the syntax function, and I have not found the change, can you help me?

---

used:intelephense

```
 $validate = $this->validation->run($data, 'register');
```

code :

```
public function  __construct()
{
    helper(['form', 'url']);
    $this->validation = \Config\Services::validation();
    $this->session = session();
}


            $data = $this->request->getPost();
            $validate = $this->validtion->run($data, 'register');
            $errors = $this->validation->getErrors();

            // Data2
            if (!$errors) {
                $this->model = new UserModel();

                $user = new \App\Entities\Users();

                $user->username        = $this->request->getPost('username');
                $user->name            = $this->request->getPost('name');
                $user->name_instansi   = $this->request->getPost('name_instansi');
                $user->alamat_instansi = $this->request->getPost('alamat_instansi');
                $user->email           = $this->request->getPost('email');
                $user->password        = $this->request->getPost('password');
                $user->repeatPassword  = $this->request->getPost('repeatPassword');


                $user->created_by = 0;

                $user->created_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                $user = $this->userModel->save($user);

                return view('login');
            }
            $this->session->setFlashdata('errors', $errors);
        }

        return view('/Geolab/auth/register');
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. The source of the error in the question title is literally in the error message. You create the `$validate` variable with the line:

```php
$validate = $this->validation->run($data, 'register');
```

But, you do not use the `$validate` variable anywhere else. Are you sure there isn't somewhere you intended to use it? Perhaps the next line down should be `$errors = $validate->getErrors()`? I can't say for sure because I don't know what your `validation` class is. But the error in your question is literally because you aren't using `$validate` anywhere else; if that's intentional, just don't create the variable and change the line to:

```php
$this->validation->run($data, 'register'); // don't save result to a variable you're not using
```